# DryIoc - Register multiple instance with ID

Tags: c#, dryioc

I want to register multiple instances of a class in a container. Each instance is identified by its ID property.

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    string Id { get; }
}

public class MyImpl : MyInterface
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public MyImpl(string id) => Id = id;
}
```

And, I want to receive this instance in the constructor of another class.

```
using DryIoc;

public class User
{
    public MyInterface Obj { get; }
    public User(string id, Func<string, MyInterface> getObj)
        => Obj = getObj(id);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Container container = new();
        container.RegisterInstance<MyInterface>(new MyImpl("A"), serviceKey: "A");
        container.RegisterInstance<MyInterface>(new MyImpl("B"), serviceKey: "B");
        container.Register<User>();
        var user = container.Resolve<Func<string, User>>()("A");
    }
}
```

This code throws ContainerException.

```
DryIoc.ContainerException: code: Error.UnableToResolveFromRegisteredServices;
message: Unable to resolve MyInterface with passed arguments [String@0] (IsWrappedInFunc, IsDirectlyWrappedInFunc)
  in wrapper Func<String, MyInterface> as parameter "getObj" WrapperExpressionFactoryWithSetup  FactoryId=158 with passed arguments [String@0] (IsWrappedInFunc)
  in User FactoryId=146 with passed arguments [String@0] (IsWrappedInFunc, IsDirectlyWrappedInFunc)
  in resolution root wrapper System.Func`2[System.String,User] WrapperExpressionFactoryWithSetup  FactoryId=158 with passed arguments [String@0]
  from container without scope
  with normal and dynamic registrations:
  ("B", {FactoryID=145, ImplType=MyImpl, Reuse=Singleton {Lifespan=1000}})  ("A", {FactoryID=144, ImplType=MyImpl, Reuse=Singleton {Lifespan=1000}})
```

The desired instance can be obtained by specifying the serviceKey in Container.Resolve(). However, since the User class is constructor-injected into another instance, we do not want to call Contaienr's methods directly.

I think that I can specify made appropriately in the argument of Register(). How should I specify it?

**Edit**

For now, create an object holder and work around the problem.

```
public static class Holder<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, T> _dictionary = new();
    public static void Add(string id, T obj) => _dictionary.Add(id, obj);
    public static void Remove(string id) => _dictionary.Remove(id);
    public static T Get(string id) => _dictionary[id];
}

interface IService
{
    string Id { get; }
}
class Service : IService
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public Service(string id) => Id = id;
}

interface IServiceUser
{
    IService Service { get; }
}

class ServiceUser : IServiceUser
{
    public IService Service { get; }
    public ServiceUser(IService service) => Service = service;
}
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(IServiceUser serviceUser)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(serviceUser.Service.Id);
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Holder<IService>.Add("A", new Service("A"));
        Holder<IService>.Add("B", new Service("B"));

        Container container = new();
        container.Register(made: Made.Of(() => Holder<IService>.Get(Arg.Of<string>())));
        container.Register<IServiceUser, ServiceUser>();
        container.Register<ViewModel>();

        var createVm = container.Resolve<Func<string, ViewModel>>();
        var vmA = createVm("A");
        var vmB = createVm("B");
    }
}
```

But since container can hold objects, I am thinking that if I can transfer the value passed in Func to serviceKey, there is no need for Holder class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace the `Func<string, MyInterface> getObj` with the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<<string, MyInterface>>> getObj` so it will serve as a dictionary to get your instance (DryIoc currently does not support `Dictionary` directly, but may be in future).

Here is the full example (https://dotnetfiddle.net/kxZCck):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using DryIoc;

public interface MyInterface
{
    string Id { get; }
}

public class MyImpl : MyInterface
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public MyImpl(string id) => Id = id;
}

public class User
{
    public MyInterface Obj { get; }
    public User(string id, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MyInterface>> getObj)
        => Obj = getObj.First(kv => kv.Key == id).Value;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Container container = new();
        container.RegisterInstance<MyInterface>(new MyImpl("A"), serviceKey: "A");
        container.RegisterInstance<MyInterface>(new MyImpl("B"), serviceKey: "B");
        container.Register<User>();
        var user = container.Resolve<Func<string, User>>()("A");
        Console.WriteLine(((MyImpl)user.Obj).Id);
    }
}
```

Here is Dictionary feature issue to track: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/issues/504

#### Update - the solution without Holder

Here is the solution where you don't need `Holder` and don't need to pollute your service constructors with dictionaries (https://dotnetfiddle.net/IAhGTg):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DryIoc;

interface IService
{
    string Id { get; }
}

class Service : IService
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public Service(string id) => Id = id;
}

interface IServiceUser
{
    IService Service { get; }
}

class ServiceUser : IServiceUser
{
    public IService Service { get; }
    public ServiceUser(IService service) => Service = service;
}

class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(IServiceUser serviceUser)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(serviceUser.Service.Id);
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        
        container.RegisterInstance<IService>(new Service("A"), serviceKey: "A");
        container.RegisterInstance<IService>(new Service("B"), serviceKey: "B");

        // Register a delegate returning a service without key selecting the result 
        // from the collection of keyed services with their keys and using the key provided by Func<string,...>
        container.RegisterDelegate<KeyValuePair<string, IService>[], string, IService>(
            (services, serviceKey) => Array.Find(services, s => s.Key == serviceKey).Value
        ); 
        
        container.Register<IServiceUser, ServiceUser>();
        container.Register<ViewModel>();

        var createVm = container.Resolve<Func<string, ViewModel>>();
        var vmA = createVm("A");
        var vmB = createVm("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your courteous reply. I am very happy that I got a direct answer from the developer.

And I am very sorry, but I think I will deal with this issue in my own Holder class.

Check out my new sample after my edits. In this sample, neither Service, ServiceUser, nor ViewMode are aware that there are multiple instances. This makes it easier to make a mock object to inject in unit tests. It may also lead to avoiding Service Locator anti-pattern (I am unfamiliar with Dependency Injection, so I may be wrong on this point...).

Comment: @ttact I have provided an alternative (elegant) solution which does not require custom Holder, and   as simple as possible.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I apologize for making you go through this twice. Thank you again for everything you’ve done.

Comment: @ttact in v6 it will be even more succint with dictionary `c.RegisterDelegate<IDictionary<string, IService>, string, IService>((d, key) => d[key]);

Comment: I will certainly update to v6. Looking forward to your release.